# Armazenar dados do checkbox de uma janela modal em uma outra view Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Pessoal preciso pegar os itens de checkbox selecionado exibindo em uma janela modal e passar para uma outra view porem preciso que esses fiquem armazenados na view e que eu possa voltar e adicionar mais dados sem perder os já inseridos.

Alguém que possa me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Em geral, a view que monta o corpo principal da página para o usuário ver é também a mesma que no final tem uma janela modal escondida, que aparece quando o usuário clica em algum lugar. Porém, mesmo que essa janela venha de outro arquivo de view, para o navegador web elas são postadas pelo mesmo controle, sequencialmente, então estariam na mesma página. Logo, via javascript ou JQuery você consegue restagar valores de formulários no corpo principal para a modal ou da modal para formulários no corpo principal.

Exemplo: exibindo um alert com o valor, via um botão no corpo principal, de um checkbox que poderia estar na modal (chame a modal, clique e veja o que aparece novamente):

`<a href="#" onclick="if($("#minha_checkbox").is(':checked')){alert('Marcado!');}else{alert("Vazio');}>Clique</a>`

Mas se há postagens de valores, ou seja, recarrega-se a página, é impossível armazenar valores na view. Você precisa receber os dados por post no controle, exemplo `$this->input->post('minha_checkbox');`, e jogar os dados que receber em sessão (do CodeIgniter), banco, flashdata ou cookie obrigatoriamente. E então, quando precisar deles, verificar quais eram, e enviar para a view, seja para a modal ou corpo principal, para continuar trabalhando com eles.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno C.Bohok, eu consegui resolver isso usando localstorage tanto para armazenar esses dados tanto para resgatar em modal ou view onde quer que seja.